# Drupal view with node reference and cck3 multigroup field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views, cck

I'm using Views2 and cck3 and am having trouble creating a Drupal view that allows me to display multigroup fields while using arguments.

Content Types:

1. **Person** (Fields: title)
2. **Quote** (Multigroups: quote, Fields: person_name, text)

Inside of the person content type I've got a field for name (title).
Inside of the quote content type, I've got a multigroup field that contains two other fields. The first is a node reference to the person content type, and the second is a text field (what is being quoted).

The thought behind this is that what is being quoted could be a dialog between 2 or more people, which is why this is in a multigroup.

> QUOTE 1
> **person a**: lorem ipsum
> **person b**: lorem ipsum dolor 
> **person a**: sit amet
>
> QUOTE 2
> **person c**: new quote text from a new person
>
> QUOTE 3
> **person a**: new quote text

I'm able to create a view that displays all of the quotes and groups dialogs similarly to how is displayed above, however I can't figure out how to create a view that does the same thing but using the person as an argument.

I don't want to use a filter as I want the url to be */quote/person-name*.

When going to */quote/person-a* it should return the entire quote for all multigroups that contain Person A.

> QUOTE 1
> **person a**: lorem ipsum
> **person b**: lorem ipsum dolor 
> **person a**: sit amet
>
> QUOTE 2
> **person a**: new quote text

but what I get are items that only contain Person A.

> QUOTE 1
> **person a**: lorem ipsum
> **person a**: sit amet
>
> QUOTE 2
> **person a**: new quote text

Playing around with various view options (like relationships) I was able to create this:

> QUOTE 1
> **person a**: lorem ipsum
> **person a**: lorem ipsum dolor 
> **person a**: sit amet
>
> QUOTE 2
> **person a**: new quote text

It contains all items in the multigroup, quote, but replaces all of the names with Person A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Multigroup, so I'm not sure if it's possible solely using Views, but I can think of two alternatives:

1) Use a Taxonomy and "tag" your Quotes with the names (or node IDs) of the people involved. This can be set up so that the tags are automatically added/updated whenever a Quote is saved.

2) Add a Computed Field to the Quote type that will hold the names as a string with some delimiter (for example, "/"). Then you can simply add an argument using that field (with the Contains operator).